# Installation of Tensorflow: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I am trying to install Tensorflow on my system(Windows-64 bit). As mention on Tensorflow website I am using the following commands.

```
pip3 install tensorflow
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

None of the above commands solves my purpose.

I have already installed Python 3.5.4 (64 bit) in my system still getting the following errors.

```
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after 
connection broken by 
‘NewConnectionError(’<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
 ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000043427F0>: Failed to 
establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed’,)’: 
/simple/tensorflow/
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from 
versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

Looking for a solution.

Comment: `ping https://pypi.python.org`? Seems like pip can't connect to package repository. Try to install any other package, e.g. `pip install wheel`. If that fails, check your internet connection/firewall etc.

Comment: @hoefling I tried `pip install wheel` . It is also showing me the same message. But when I tried `pip install numpy` , it was installed successfully.

Comment: Alternatively, you can download the wheel from this site: `http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#tensorflow`

Comment: @ankush-bandil: did you install numpy before? Why I'm asking: pip stores installation files (wheels or tar archives) in cache on disk so when reinstalling a package, pip won't redownload the files, using the cached ones instead. Try `pip uninstall -y numpy && pip install numpy --no-cache-dir` to force redownloading the files from package repo - will this work?

Comment: @ankush-bandil: sure, you can download the package wheel via browser or wget or whatever and install tensorflow from file system. In your case, it should be the [cp35-win64 wheel](https://pypi.python.org/packages/dc/80/c2cdd8afa7a7610b3d0f9e9799d1d3f2380ab7464e980171bb3e0d65cdb1/tensorflow-1.3.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl#md5=63297f21e295bc6bddf1fc0d67a8ad9f). Download the file, when issue `pip install C:\path\to\wheel`.

Comment: But keep in mind that once a package has any dependencies, pip will try to download them either and fail anyway, so you're best with fixing the connection issue, or you will have to manually download all the dependencies and install them first.

Comment: @hoefling: I tried to install from downloaded package wheel also but the same issue is there.

Comment: @ankush-bandil: Please update your question with the full installation log. Also, if you try to reinstall `numpy` with the `--no-cache-dir` arg, does the installation succeed?